# How to mock PoolDataSource using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class to get the metrics of my connection pool:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConnectionPoolMetrics {

    @Inject
    @Named("appDs")
    private PoolDataSource appDs;

    protected PoolDataSource getPoolDataSource() {
        return appDs;
    }

    @Gauge(unit = MetricUnits.NONE, name = "pool_connections_total_count", description = "Display the number of total connections in pool", absolute = true)
    public int getActiveConnectionsCount() {
        JDBCConnectionPoolStatistics stats = _getStatistics();
        if (null != stats) {
            return stats.getTotalConnectionsCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private JDBCConnectionPoolStatistics _getStatistics() {
        PoolDataSource pds = getPoolDataSource();

        if (pds != null) {
            return pds.getStatistics();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I want to test this class, by mocking the PoolDataSource and making it return some test statistics so that I test the methods that fetch individual stat.

How can I do this? Is something like below possible?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ConnectionPoolMetricsTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ConnectionPoolMetrics connectionPoolMetrics;

    @Mock
    PoolDataSource testDs;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        Mockito.when(testDs.getStatistics()).thenReturn(<custom stats>);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try ,     `@BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        Mockito.when(connectionPoolMetrics.getPoolDataSource()).thenReturn(testDs);
    }`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it throws the following exception on the line you mentioned above `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
`

Comment: If you can , change the `getPoolDataSource` to `public` on `ConnectionPoolMetrics`

Comment: Made `getPoolDataSource` to public, and re-ran test, it still throws the exception mentioned above.

Comment: I think also you need to not mock `ConnectionPoolMetrics` injection , because  you want to test the method inside it , so inject `ConnectionPoolMetrics` as normal bean and to it inject the mock `PoolDataSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test the class in the following manner:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@DisplayName("ConnectionPoolMetrics Unit Tests")
public class ConnectionPoolMetricsTest {

    private static final int TOTAL_CONNECTIONS_COUNT = 2;

    @Spy
    ConnectionPoolMetrics connectionPoolMetrics;

    @Mock
    PoolDataSource testDs;

    @Mock
    JDBCConnectionPoolStatistics testStats;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        Mockito.when(connectionPoolMetrics.getPoolDataSource()).thenReturn(testDs);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("getActiveConnectionsCount - Should return TOTAL_CONNECTIONS_COUNT")
    void testGetActiveConnectionsCount() {
        Mockito.when(testStats.getTotalConnectionsCount()).thenReturn(TOTAL_CONNECTIONS_COUNT);
        Mockito.when(testDs.getStatistics()).thenReturn(testStats);

        assertEquals(TOTAL_CONNECTIONS_COUNT, connectionPoolMetrics.getActiveConnectionsCount());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("getActiveConnectionsCount - Should return 0 when PoolDataSource is null")
    void testGetActiveConnectionsCountWithNullPds() {
        Mockito.when(connectionPoolMetrics.getPoolDataSource()).thenReturn(null);

        assertEquals(0, connectionPoolMetrics.getActiveConnectionsCount());
    }
}
```